# Editing "About Me" portion of the profile on iPad returns an "unusual error"

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, profile-page, ipad

When attempting to save changes made the "About Me" section of my Stack Overflow profile while using an iPad, I encountered this error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating
> your profile:
>
> - unusual error updating your profile - please try again!

I was able to edit and save my profile a few moments later on my desktop without a problem. I tried once more with the iPad with the same error coming up.

My updated profile includes HTML and is maybe 300 or so characters in length. When I attempted to save my profile a second time after having changed it on my desktop, I simply clicked `Save Profile` without making any changes.

Comment: Does this occur with any changes at all? Or is it a specific change or set of changes?

Comment: @Grace: Updated my post. Hopefully it's a bit more clear.

Comment: Very nice and much clearer. Thanks! I hope this helps identify the source of the unusual error.

Comment: I also see this problem.

Comment: Questions about iPad are *off-topic* on Super User, voting to.... erm, sorry.

Comment: This also appears to be happening on the iPhone, reported here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56041/oops-theres-a-problem-updating-my-profile-from-my-iphone

Answer (score 3):

This was an issue in some specific javascript we embed for mobile devices - a fix will be pushed tonight.

Comment: Thanks Jarrod. I can confirm this is now working on my iPhone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same "Oops..." error that started this thread. I am using an iPhone 3G running iOS 3.1.2 and accessing the site from Safari. I would update to iOS 4.0.2, but that would break the unlock of my phone. I will update my user info from my laptop the next time I'm at an internet cafe, but it would be nice to see this fixed for the next user who tries using it.

Comment: @user150913 a javascript refactoring broke this again; a fix is being pushed tonight.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error, but not on an iPad (I own no Apple products).

I run NoScript on Firefox so that I can whitelist JavaScript from trusted sources.  I found I got this error until I allowed access to http://sstatic.net — then the relevant scripts could run and the profile was updated.

If anyone runs across this error on a desktop, this may be the cause.

Comment: that's definitely related, thanks for sharing the tip with others