# Oops! There's a problem updating my profile from my iPhone

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, profile-page, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Editing “About Me” portion of the profile on iPad returns an “unusual error”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55295/editing-about-me-portion-of-the-profile-on-ipad-returns-an-unusual-error)

A relatively minor bug, tested on iPhone 4 in both Safari and Opera Mini. Any changes I make to my profile on SO cannot be saved.  I get the following message:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> - unusual error updating your profile -- please try again!

I've repro'd several times on two separate days.

Comment: On the plus side, I learned how to take screenshots with the iphone :-)

Comment: Related, on the iPad instead of the iPhone: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55295/editing-about-me-portion-of-the-profile-on-ipad-returns-an-unusual-error. Maybe they're related?

Comment: Sure sounds like the same problem, whatever it is.

Comment: ...wow, my previous comment looks stupid. `"This is related, maybe they're related?"`, pwa? I meant to say "Maybe they're the same problem?"

Comment: Hmm, didn't see that - I looked through every question in the [iphone] tag, didn't think about [ipad] at all!  Voted to close as dupe, it's probably better to edit the other question to include the details posted here.

Comment: @Glorfindel That doesn't appear to be the correct image in this case. It seems like the actual image behind the link changed.

Comment: Right, thanks for catching that.